# Foreach loop not using to remove old entry exception caught (Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute)

Tags: c#, listview, exception, foreach, datagridview

> I know this is a duplicate question but i'm here looking for code
>   error **I've using datagirdview to show data during live capturing and i'm using foreach to capture new and add new entry as soon as it detect packet.**

but the issue is after receiving 4,5 packets it gave me exception i already tried some method but nothing work out for me for demo purpose the **raw code** is given below:

```
URLData.Add(urlclass);

foreach(var x in URLData)
{   
    dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { dgvPacket.Rows.Add(); ; }));

    dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = x.PktCount; ; }));

    // dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.dgvPacket.Rows.Add(); ; }));

    dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = x.SourceIP; ; }));

    dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = x.HttpMethod; ; }));

    dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = x.HttpVersion.ToString(); ; }));

    dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value = x.URLString.ToString(); ; }));

    if (x.UserAgent == null)
    {
        txtCapture.AppendText(" -\t");
        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText(" -\t")));
    }
    else
    {
        // rtbTest.AppendText(x.UserAgent + "\t");
        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText(x.UserAgent + "\t")));
        this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value = x.UserAgent;


    }
    if (x.URLReferer == null)

        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText("-\t")));

    else

        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText(x.URLReferer + "\t")));
    this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value = x.URLReferer;
    if (x.ContentType == null)
    {

        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText(" -\t")));
    }
    else
    {
        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText(x.ContentType + "\t")));

        this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[7].Value = x.ContentType;
    }
    if (x.HttpCookie == null)
    {

        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText(" -\t")));

    }
    else
    {
        txtCapture.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCapture.AppendText(x.HttpCookie + "\t")));
        this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value = x.HttpCookie;
    }

    index++;
}
```

Comment: normally to stop that error, use a descending for loop, not foreach as you then remove the old entry and arent indanger of missing items in the loop, if you make a local copy of x and send it to a function to do all those items it will be easier.

Comment: Sound good can you give a demo in answer?

Comment: Are you trying to process a list of items and remove items that have been processed while simultaneously adding new items? I can't tell from the question - I'm trying to infer that from other comments and answers. If that's the case then you may want a `Queue` or `ConcurrentQueue`. Instead of processing items by iterating over them you process items by taking the next one from the queue. That allows you to modify the collection you're processing as you process it. If I'm in the ballpark of understanding the problem I can post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach does not work with Collections. It works with Enumerators. If you give it a collection, those usually implement "IEnumerable" so converting them is trivial.

And Enumerators have a few rules. One of them is: If the underlying collection is changed, the Enumerator is invalid. It **must** throws an exception.

The result is: You can **not** modify a collection you loop over via foreach. You need to use any of the other loops to do it. A while would usually be a good bet.

```
List<int> input; //Set some other place
int i = 0;

while(i < input.Count){
  int current = input[i];

  if(/*do some check on current*/)
    //advance i
    i++;
  else
    //Do something like removing the element at i
}
```

Comment: Only problem with counting upwards is that if you have 10 things, and remove number 6, and still add 1.. you skip what was old 6...

Comment: That is why counting up and removing are seperate twigs of the if check. If you got nothing to remove: Count up. Otherwise remove.

Comment: Thanks i didn't try this let me try this